# C++ (MFC) : Can't get buttons working in kinect sample project

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, mfc, kinect

Hi I'm new to C++ and MFC. I'm working with this kinect sample project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973081.aspx

I can't seem to add a button in designer view and get it to work in this project why is that?

Comment: I added an exit(0); on button click but nothing happens

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: For the program to exit of course